# How to remove a member from a JSON object using YoJson?

Tags: json, ocaml

I am trying to functionally remove a member of a `Yojson.Safe.t`.

For example:

```json
{
  id: 123,
  name: "bob",
  roles: ["admin", "user"]
}
```

If I was to remove the id member, the result would look like:

```json
{
  name: "bob",
  roles: ["admin", "user"]
}
```

I originally thought that something like this would do it:

```ml
Yojson.Safe.Util.to_assoc json 
|> List.filter (fun (t, _) -> t != "id")
|> fun t -> `Assoc t
```

But for some reason it keeps the member anyways. How can I remove a member from a `Yojson.Safe.t`?

Comment: Since OCaml 4.08, there is `List.filter_map` which may be of interest here. ``Yojson.Safe.Util.to_assoc json |> List.filter_map (fun (t, _) -> if t <> "id" then Some (`Assoc t) else None)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `!=` to compare strings! Use `<>`:

```
# "abc" != "abc";;
- : bool = true
# "abc" <> "abc";;
- : bool = false
```

The `!=` operator is "physical inequality", i.e., the inverse of the `==` operator. These are not for general use, especially not on immutable values.

The workhorse operators for comparison are `=` and `<>`.